# Why is "require UIExplorerBlock" and "require UIExplorerPage" required for some Components?

Tags: react-native

In react-native for components such as ToolbarAndroid, Switch, ProcessBar, ToastAndroid, ListView, etc. the following is required and I have not been able to find an explanation why this is necessary:

```
var UIExplorerBlock = require('./UIExplorerBlock');
var UIExplorerPage = require('./UIExplorerPage');
```

and respectively

```
<UIExplorerPage>
  <UIExplorerBlock>
    ..
  </UIExplorerBlock>
</UIExplorerPage>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those components are part of the [UI Explorer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer) sample application. They are using them to keep the sample code DRY.

You should not be using the `UIExplorer*` components in your own code.